# Android: SQLite gets wrong data

Tags: android, sqlite

My issue is that when I open the ViewContact class, all fields are blank except for name, which displays the notes entry. Im not experienced in SQLite, or databases in general. I'll post all related code. I think it may be something with the cursor, but again, I dont know much about this yet. Thank you for any help.

ContactsMenu class

```
package com.emailandcontactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ContactsMenu extends Activity {


    ListView listView;
    public static final String fields[] = { DatabaseSetup.colName, DatabaseSetup.colMail, DatabaseSetup.colPhone1,
                                                DatabaseSetup.colPhone2,  DatabaseSetup.colAddress,  DatabaseSetup.colNotes };
    Cursor cursor;

    public static String name, email, phone1, phone2, address, notes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.managecontacts);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContacts); 
        DatabaseSetup.init(this); 

        Button btnAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddContact);
        btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent addItem = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddContact.class);
            startActivity(addItem);
        }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
                int position, long id) {
        // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            //cursor = DatabaseSetup.getContactData();
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                String selectedName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
                String selectedEmail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Email"));
                String selectedPhone1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Phone1"));
                String selectedPhone2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Phone2"));
                String selectedAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Address"));
                String selectedNotes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Notes"));

                setName(selectedName);
                setName(selectedEmail);
                setName(selectedPhone1);
                setName(selectedPhone2);
                setName(selectedAddress);
                setName(selectedNotes);


                Intent viewItem = new Intent(view.getContext(), ViewContact.class);
                startActivity(viewItem);

        }
        }); 

    }
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            listView.setAdapter(null);
            cursor.close();
            DatabaseSetup.deactivate();
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            DatabaseSetup.init(this);
            //Updated
            cursor = DatabaseSetup.getContactData(); 
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, fields, new int[] {R.id.item_text,
                                                                R.id.item_text2,  R.id.item_text3,  R.id.item_text4,
                                                                R.id.item_text5,  R.id.item_text6})
            listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
        }

        public void setName(String selectedName) {
            name = selectedName;
        }

        public void setEmail(String selectedEmail) {
            email = selectedEmail;
        }

        public void setPhone1(String selectedPhone1) {
            phone1 = selectedPhone1;
        }

        public void setPhone2(String selectedPhone2) {
            phone2 = selectedPhone2;
        }

        public void setAddress(String selectedAddress) {
            address = selectedAddress;
        }

        public void setNotes(String selectedNotes) {
            notes = selectedNotes;
        }


        public static String getName() {
            String itemName = name;
            return itemName;        
        }

        public static String getEmail() {
            String itemEmail = email;
            return itemEmail;       
        }

        public static String getPhone1() {
            String itemPhone1 = phone1;
            return itemPhone1;      
        }

        public static String getPhone2() {
            String itemPhone2 = phone2;
            return itemPhone2;      
        }

        public static String getAddress() {
            String itemAddress = address;
            return itemAddress;     
        }

        public static String getNotes() {
            String itemNotes = notes;
            return itemNotes;       
        }

////////////////MENU////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            switch (which){ 
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE: 
                finish();
                break; 

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: 
                //Nothing happens on No button click, and the menu closes
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    }; 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu mainmenu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, mainmenu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Contacts list", "Add Contact"};

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.help:     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                                builder.setTitle("Select a function to revice information about it.");
                                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selected) {
                                        switch(selected){
                                        case 0:
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Allows you to view the selected item and make editations to it or delete it.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            break;
                                        case 1:
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Allows you to add a new contact by bringing up a screen where the nececary information can be entered.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.show();
                                break;

                                case R.id.back:     AlertDialog.Builder builderBack = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
                                                    builderBack.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener) 
                                                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show(); 
                                break;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

ViewContacts class

```
package com.emailandcontactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewContact extends Activity {

    EditText nameField, mailield, phoneField1, phoneField2, addressField, notesField;

    String name, mail, phone1, phone2, address, notes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewcontact);

        nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textName);
        mailield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textMail);
        phoneField1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPhone1);
        phoneField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPhone2);
        addressField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textAddress);
        notesField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNotes);

        name =ContactsMenu.getName();
        mail =ContactsMenu.getEmail();
        phone1 =ContactsMenu.getPhone1();
        phone2 =ContactsMenu.getPhone2();
        address =ContactsMenu.getAddress();
        notes =ContactsMenu.getNotes();

        nameField.setText(name, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        mailield.setText(mail, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        phoneField1.setText(phone1, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        phoneField2.setText(phone2, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        addressField.setText(address, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        notesField.setText(notes, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        Button btnEditContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditContact);
        btnEditContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editContact();
        }
        });

        Button btnDeleteContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditContact);
        btnDeleteContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteContact();
        }
        });

        Button btnEditTags = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEditContact);
        btnEditTags.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent editTags = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditContactTags.class);
            startActivity(editTags);
        }
        });
    }

    public void editContact(){

    }

    public void deleteContact(){

    }

}
```

DatabaseSetup class

```
package com.emailandcontactmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; 

/* 
 * usage:  
 * DatabaseSetup.init(egActivityOrContext); 
 * DatabaseSetup.createEntry() or DatabaseSetup.getContactNames() or DatabaseSetup.getDb() 
 * DatabaseSetup.deactivate() then job done 
 */ 

class DatabaseSetup extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
static DatabaseSetup instance = null; 
static SQLiteDatabase db = null; 

public static void init(Context context) { 
    if (null == instance) { 
        instance = new DatabaseSetup(context); 
        } 
    } 

public static SQLiteDatabase getDb() { 
    if (null == db) { 
        db = instance.getWritableDatabase(); 
        } 
    return db; 
    } 

public static void deactivate() { 
    if (null != db && db.isOpen()) { 
        db.close(); 
        } 
    db = null; 
    instance = null; 
    } 

public static long createEntry(String name, String mail, String phone1, 
        String phone2, String address, String notes) { 
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
    cv.put(colName, name); 
    cv.put(colMail, mail); 
    cv.put(colPhone1, phone1); 
    cv.put(colPhone2, phone2); 
    cv.put(colAddress, address); 
    cv.put(colNotes, notes); 
    return getDb().insert(contactsTable, null, cv); 

    } 
/*  Old 
public static Cursor getContactNames() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", colName }; 
    return getDb().query(contactsTable, columns, null, null, null, null, 
            null); 
    } 
*/
public static Cursor getContactData(){
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", colName, colMail, colPhone1, colPhone2, colAddress, colNotes }; 
    return getDb().query(contactsTable, columns, null, null, null, null, 
            null); 
    }

DatabaseSetup(Context context) { 
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion); 
    } 

@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + contactsTable 
            + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + colName 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colMail + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colPhone1 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colPhone2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + colAddress + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colNotes 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL)"); 

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + templatesTable 
            + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + colSubject 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colBody + " TEXT NOT NULL)"); 

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tagsTable 
            + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + colTagName 
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colContact + " TEXT NOT NULL)"); 

    } 

@Override 
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + contactsTable); 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + templatesTable); 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tagsTable); 
    onCreate(db); 
    } 

static final String dbName = "DB"; 
static final int dbVersion = 1; 
static final String contactsTable = "Contacts"; 
static final String colName = "Name"; 
static final String colMail = "Email"; 
static final String colPhone1 = "Phone1"; 
static final String colPhone2 = "Phone2"; 
static final String colAddress = "Address"; 
static final String colNotes = "Notes"; 

static final String templatesTable = "Templates"; 
static final String colSubject = "Subject"; 
static final String colBody = "Body"; 

static final String tagsTable = "Tags"; 
static final String colTagName = "Name"; 
static final String colContact = "Contact"; 

}
```

Logcat entry

```
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.emailandcontactmanager/com.emailandcontactmanager.ContactsMenu}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4138a990
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2443)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1172)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4138a990
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4508)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2433)
10-22 14:49:51.418: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: Please post minimum compilable code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: He means less code, not more :)

Comment: Why are you using `Cursor`? Is this something Android-specific? Can you go just with custom SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using the `SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)` correctly. You have `from` array containing the columns you want to show from the table and the `to` array should contain the views to show the columns to.

You should have number of fields in `to` equals to `from`, else you will have the behaviour you have which is only the first column in `from` is mapped to `R.id.item_text`.

**Update:**

Since you only want to show the name column to show, then do not use the ListView to fill the cursor `cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);`. You should replace:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

with:

```
Cursor cursor = DatabaseSetup.getContactData();
StartManagingCursor(cursor);
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Since you use this `cursor` later to fill the values passed to the other Activity, you can't get it from `listView.getItemAtPosition(position);` because there is only one item at position `position` (which is the name column), so the other items give `NullPointerException` as they do not exist in the `cursor` returned from `listView.getItemAtPosition(position);`

**Update 2:**

Also:

```
setName(selectedName);
setName(selectedEmail);
setName(selectedPhone1);
setName(selectedPhone2);
setName(selectedAddress);
setName(selectedNotes);
```

Should be:

```
setName(selectedName);
setEmail(selectedEmail);
setPhone1(selectedPhone1);
setPhone2(selectedPhone2);
setAddress(selectedAddress);
setNotes(selectedNotes);
```

Comment: Ive updated my code, as it is, the listView not displays all contact information(I only want the name displayed there.) and the ViewContact class still displays incorrectly. Where is my issue?

Comment: Ive used the updated code but now I get a cursor out of bounds exception. I'll update the logcat code.

Comment: Yes, you just need to open the cursor and move to its start, I updated the answer. (startManagingCursor is deprecated, however, it still works. Better, You can use LoadManager instead, but I haven't tried it before)

Comment: Ive updated my code, but Im still having the original issue where my ViewContact class is only filling one field, and with the wrong data.

Comment: Check Update 2, you forgot to change the function to update the different variables.

Comment: Thanks, geeze thats quite the mistake. Sorry about that, sometimes you just cant see such a simple error in your own code. Well if you dont mind I dont understand why the appliaction crashes when I return to the ContactsMenu class. I'll update the logcat, this should be the last issue.

Comment: It is already stated in the LogCat, you are trying to requery a closed cursor. You should move the cursor part to onResume() because when the App returns to the previous Activity, the cursor is already closed and not reopen (cursor creation is in onCreate() which only runs when the App starts) so when the listview tries to refresh, it finds the cursor closed

Comment: When you say I creted it in my oncreate method, you mean the setOnItemClickListener. I dont fully understand, when I put the lines from your first update into the onResume methpod, the program crashes. If I put it into the setOnItemClickListener. however it works until I go back to the ContactsMenu class. can you explain this?

Comment: You did not add startManagingCursor in onResume()